# calculate the same amount of data on mysql using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to calculate the same amount of data in one field as in this database

[image: tbl_order]

Code Model "M_profile"

```
class M_profile extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_count()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT count(kd_order) as total FROM tbl_order WHERE kd_pelanggan group by kd_order";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $result->row()->total;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some problem with the code you provided?

Comment: Yes, this problem

Message: Trying to get property 'total' of non-object

Filename: models/M_profile.php

Line Number: 10

Comment: The error suggests that your query is returning 0 rows. Have you tried executing it directly on the database? Your query looks incomplete to me. `WHERE kd_pelanggan`, should be `WHERE kd_pelanggan = 'PL0008'` .

Answer (score 0):

Using the query builder instead of writing the queries yourself is always a good idea.

From what I see of your table your function should look something like this:

```
class M_profile extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_count()
    {
        $this->db->select('count(kd_order) as total');
        $this->db->group_by('kd_order')
        $q = $this->db->get('tbl_order');
        return $q->row()->total;
    }
}
```

This way you'll get all the items grouped by order.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear to me. I am little bit confused. If you want to count based on a condition, you should be put `where` with a value like this:

```
class M_profile extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_count()
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('COUNT(kd_order) as total')
                      ->where('kd_pelanggan', $your_value)
                      ->group_by('kd_order')
                      ->get('tbl_order');
        return $query->row()->total;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to count without any condition then try this:

```
class M_profile extends CI_Model
    {
        public function get_count()
        {
            $query = $this->db->select('COUNT(kd_order) as total')
                          ->group_by('kd_order')
                          ->get('tbl_order');
            return $query->row()->total;
        }
    }
```